# Add a section of order items with buttons to WooCommerce My Account single order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, account

In WooCommerce, when customers purchase one or more products, he can see in his My Account section on single order pages:

> [image]

I would like in this My Account section on single order pages to add a section listing all order items *(purchased products)* for the current order with a button for each order item, so the user will see, by default, the following:

> [image]

I'm using this code to display a button and I want the following conditions to be checked when he clicks on the button for each product he bought:

1. First, check if this product was purchased by the same user who clicked on the (Download this product invoice) button?
2. If the product was purchased, a text file should be generated and the name of the same product that the buyer clicks on the corresponding button (Download this product invoice) and puts the buyer's email address in that file and then the file is downloaded (text file like be below)
3. A button (Download this product invoice) should be created in front of or for each product that was purchased

> Hello, dear user Thank you for purchasing (**virtual product 1**). You can
> receive your invoice by (**buyer's email**).

or

> Hello, dear user Thank you for purchasing (**virtual product 2**). You can
> receive your invoice by (**buyer's email**).

and...

I myself have used the following commands to add the button to the Function.php file, but I want to apply the above changes

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'add_button');

function add_button($order) {
    /* Your code */
   // echo "Your button html code";
    echo '<form method="post">';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="btn-added" id="btn-added" value="Download this product invoice" /><br/>';
    echo '</form>';
}


function sample_func() {
    // Get Current User Email Address
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $current_user_email = $current_user->user_email;
    echo $current_user_email;
    
    // Get Order Id
    $order_id_sample = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    echo $order_id_sample;   
}

if(array_key_exists('btn-added',$_POST)){
   sample_func();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to hook your function in  `woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table` action hook instead.

Note that you don't need to *"check if this product was purchased by the same user who clicked on the (Download this product invoice)"* as My Account section is only displayed to Logged in Customers with their orders and personal data.

The following function code will display in each customer My account single orders, an additional section with all order items listed *(products names)* with your custom download button:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', 'section_order_items_button_invoice');

function section_order_items_button_invoice( $order ) {
    if ( ! is_account_page() ) return; // Only on customer my account section

    // Only for 'completed' and 'processing' orders
    if ( $order->has_status( array('completed', 'processing') ) ) :

    $user_id   = $order->get_user_id(); // Get the customer ID
    $user      = $order->get_user(); // Get the WP_User object
   ?> 
    <section class="woocommerce-order-details product-invoices">
        <h2 class="woocommerce-order-details__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product Order details', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
        <!-- form start -->
        <form method="post" name="<?php echo 'download-' . $user_id; ?>">
            <table class="woocommerce-table woocommerce-table--order-details shop_table order_details">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                        <th class="woocommerce-table__product-table product-total"><?php esc_html_e( 'Invoice download', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    // Loop through order items
                    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) :
                        $product            = $item->get_product();
                        $product_id         = $item->get_variation_id() ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id();
                    ?>
                    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'woocommerce-table__line-item order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">

                        <td class="woocommerce-table__product-name product-name"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $item->get_name() );?></td>

                        <td class="woocommerce-table__product-total product-total"><?php printf( 
                            '<input type="submit" name="%s" value="%s" /><br/>',
                            'product_item-' . $item_id . '-' . $product_id, // Unique imput name with the item ID and the product ID
                            esc_html__(  'Download this product invoice', 'woocommerce')
                        ); ?></td>

                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </form>
        <!-- form end -->
    </section>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

You will have to handle yourself the download functionality of every order item invoice and everything else you asked (as this is simply too broad and complicated to be handled in Stack overflow).

Note that the `<form>` element just need to be implemented **once** in the page, with a unique `name` attribute. Also, for each `<input type="submit" name="">` each `name` attribute need to be unique.

Tested in the theme's functions.php file and works, displaying the following:

[image]

Comment: that was perfect 
Can you please guide me how to handle each button so that on clicking each button the following command will be (echo) printed (I know this is a very simple and superficial question but I want to learn the best way from you):
`
echo $current_user_email;
<br>
echo $current_product_name and $current_product_id;
`

Comment: @Salvadora Sorry but you should ask a new question providing the necessary code, details and explanations.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course

Comment: I have a problem using the above code, when the order is in trouble during payment for any reason and the order is in Pending payment status, in the order section, by clicking on the order that has not been completed, download buttons (Download this product invoice) will be displayed. It will be given! How can I prevent this problem? (I want these links to be displayed only when the payment is successful) Thank you again

Comment: @Salvadora I have updated my code for pending orders.

Comment: Thank you, dear @LoicTheAztec
Unfortunately, there is this problem in Canceled mode too! Is it possible to set the condition in such a way that the condition is established and implemented only in the case of successful payment?

Comment: Updated to allow only orders with 'completed' or 'processing' status. If you want only "completed" orders change `array('completed', 'processing')`to `array('completed')`…

Comment: It was great and works without problems. I have a question similar to this one, should I ask a new question or wait for the answer to this question?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76570579/21197857)

Comment: There will be no answer to the linked question, as the answer is to use a custom function with a personalized version of `wp_kses()` including all allowed HTML tags and attributes, to have an effective sanitization.